# Where is the Database stored in Orbeon forms CE?

Tags: settings, orbeon

I am using "Orbeon Forms CE" edition.. I biuld number of forms.. I think each form  should have it's own database..So we can access it. So I wanna to find where the database of the created form exists as well as username and password....

Answer (score 0):

The forms are stored in an embedded eXist XML database. You shouldn't use this for production. Instead, set up a [relational database](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/persistence/relational-db) such as MySQL or PostgreSQL.